# PyCharm Code Inspection doesn't include PEP 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, pep8

How do I get PyCharm 2.7 Code Inspection (under Code > Inspect Code) to include PEP 8 messages?

In the Inspection settings I have "PEP 8 coding style violation" checked and the correct profile selected, but running the inspection does not include any PEP 8 violations.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - you care about PEP8 compliance ^^ Just kidding of course, but I think PEP8 contains some rather questionable parts, most notably the 80-character limit on lines; even the preface states these are just guidelines and should be ignored if it benefits readability, so a literal PEP8 checker could become annoying. Regarding the problem, [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9157) seems to be related. In general, this seems more like a question for the pycharm support than for SO...

Answer (score 2):

PEP8 inspections are not reported from `Code` | `Inspect Code`, there is a [known issue about it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9157), please vote.

**UPDATE**: the issue was fixed, should be available starting from 3.0.2 release.

Comment: Looks like this was just fixed in Build 132.934 (04 Nov 2013).  I'm using the community edition (Latest Build 131.190), so I can't verify this yet.